# SQL Server call results in 'net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET' error in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I'm messing up with some problem with prepared queries using PDO-ODBC with PHP5.5 and SQL Server 2008.

I am able to connect to the database using the SQL Server Native Client 10.0 of ODBC and do some unprepared queries when I am hard encoding the value I am searching for.

The problem happens when I am trying to do prepared queries... the browser is simply telling me that the page is not accessible... The status is not even a 404 Error but it tells me:

> (failed)
>
> net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.

The code I am using is :

```
    try {
        $pdodb = new PDO('odbc:Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=xx.xx.xx.xx; database=test; UID=idUser; PWD=password');
    } catch (Exception $exc) {
        echo $exc->getMessage();
    }
$name= 'Smith';
$query = "SELECT * FROM users where Name= :name";


$pdodb->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
$sql = $pdodb->prepare($query);
$sql->bindParam(':name',$name, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$sql->execute();

$response = $sql->fetchAll();
```